# How to configure Review Board running under linux to use a LDAP user

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap

I have installed ReviewBoard before on windows successfully. I am now trying to install it on Ubuntu.

Steps so far:

1. Successfully installed
   ReviewBoard (can login into the web
   app)
2. Connected Ubuntu to the
   windows Domain.
3. I can successfully
   login as the user I wish to run
   ReviewBoard under.
4. Tried to change
   /var/www/review/apache-mod-python.conf to have the something like the following (NOTE: These aren't actually my details)

   AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=LookUp,ou=People,dc=masd,dc=edu"
       AuthLDAPBindPassword masdsearch
       AuthLDAPAuthoritative off
       AuthLDAPCompareDNOnServer On
       AuthLDAPURL ldap://server1.masd.edu/ou=People,dc=masd,dc=edu?sAMAccountName

However doing all this when i try and post to review board from my local machine I get the following error

Error uploading diff: One or more fields had errors (105)

> > > {u'fields': {u'path': [u'HTTPS certificate not accepted.  Please ensure that the proper certificate exists in /var/www/.subversion/auth for the user that reviewboard is running as.']}, u'stat': u'fail', u'err': {u'msg': u'One or more fields had errors', u'code': 105}}

Does anyone have ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using the following method

SVN checkout a file under the user Reviewboard is running under this will create a .Subversion/Auth/ directory in that users HOME.

I then simply recreated the .Suberversion/Auth/ directory in /var/www/ and everyhting worked as expected